# How to remove namespace prefix ns2 from Soap body in Apache CXF

Tags: java, spring, soap, jaxb, cxf

I am using Apache Cxf for creating webservice like below:

```
@WebService(name = "xmlServiceSoap", targetNamespace = "http://www.Test.com/")
@BindingType(value = javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
public class MyEndpoint {
    @Autowired
        MyServiceImpl myServiceImpl;

        @WebMethod(action = "http://www.Test.com/MyService")
        @WebResult(name = "MyServiceResponse",targetNamespace="http://www.Test.com/")
        @SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = ParameterStyle.BARE)
        public MyServiceResponse getMyServiceResponse(
                @WebParam(name = "MyService", targetNamespace = "http://www.Test.com/") MyService partnerService,
                @WebParam(name = "AuthenticationHeader", header = true, targetNamespace = "http://www.Test.com/") AuthenticationHeader header) {

            MyServiceResponse res = myServiceImpl.getMyServiceResponse(partnerService, header);
            return res;
        }
}
```

The problem is that I am getting response like below:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:MyServiceResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.HotelTravel.com/">
         <MyServiceResult>
```

But I want response like:

```
<soap:Body>
  <MyServiceResponse xmlns="http://www.HotelTravel.com/">
     <MyServiceResult>
```

means `removinf ns2` in `soap:body`. 
Is it possible to achieve this in CXF?

Comment: Did you manage to do this?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to double check the namespace params of your classes
this should be something like

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Foo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "YourName", namespace = "http://your.name.space/")
public class MyServiceResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "Foo", required = true, namespace = "http://your.name.space/")
    private String foo;
```

instead of

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Foo", namespace = "http://your.name.space/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "YourName")
public class MyServiceResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "Foo")
    private String foo;
```

And your service interface must not contain targetNamespace param, only but in @WebService